# Mysql query browser (an external program) cant see all databases

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database to work with. There is phpMyAdmin and it works good but I want to use an external database manager. I use the same login account what PhP script uses, still query browser doesnt see a database.
Anyone can know why?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that with phpMyAdmin, you are accessing MySQL from the WebServer that has IP address `1.0.0.1`.

Then, from the external DB manager, you are accessing from IP address `1.0.0.2`.

MySQL handles authentication and authorization using IP address (among other things) to authorize. So it's probably the case that you don't have all permissions for `1.0.0.2` in your MySQL database.

Comment: The USER_PRIVILEGES looks like this:
GRANTE: 'dbName'@'%'
TABLE_CATALOG: null
PRIVILEGE_TYPE: USAGE
IS_GRANTABLE: NO

Answer (score 0):

Your account is probably limited to 'localhost' only, try adding 'user'@'remote-ip' aswell.
For example:

```
GRANT ALL ON db.* TO 'jsmith'@'office.example.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Im not sure if there error is with grants. If I query grans (SHOW GRANTS): 2 record: GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'xxxx'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'complicatedstring';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xxxx\_%`.* TO 'xxxx'@'%'